# Why IO12 is connected to 3V3 in ESP32-PICO-DevKit schematic?

Tags: datasheet, esp32

Here, IO12 is connected to 3V3.

https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/SCH_ESP32-PICO-DEVKITM-2_V1_0_20200812A.pdf

The only clue about this that I found is below.

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/hw-reference/esp32/get-started-pico-devkitm-2.html#get-started-pico-devkitm-2-pin-notes

Here, in IO12, it said `see 3`.

> The operating voltage of ESP32-PICO-DevKitM-2’s embedded SPI flash is 3.3 V. Therefore, the strapping pin MTDI should be pulled down during the module power-on reset. If connected, please make sure that this pin is not held up on reset.

But it is more confusing. [Datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-pico-mini-02_datasheet_en.pdf) said it is default pull-down...
[image: datasheet]

Comment: This can be explanation... https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/esp32/advanced-topics/boot-mode-selection.html#other-pins